# How to detect when a ListView or any control is finished rendering?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, uno-platform

I am working on a Uno project using both UWP And WASM.  The project contains a ListView or GridView with a source that is an ObservableCollection.  Since it is getting data from an API. I am displaying a progress indicator, what I am finding is that the progress indicator stays active until the ObservableCollection is populated with data items.

The issue is that there is a lag between when the ObservableCollection has the data and when the control is finished rendering the view.  In this case, it is an ObservableCollection of images and the GridView or ListView does not populate.

I have not been able to identify and event that will tell me when to inactivate the progress indicator.

Comment: What about using  `progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;` ??

Answer (score 1):

There's no event defined in the WinUI API that tells you when the UI has completed rendering, so you have to create your own. This can be worthwhile when you have a complex, heavy UI that takes a visible delay to render after it's obtained data.

There are a few possible strategies:

- hide the progress indicator after a fixed delay.
- Schedule a callback using `CoreDispatcher.RunIdleAsync()`. This should only be raised when the UI thread is not 'busy', which is a rough proxy for it having completed rendering. Eg: `Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(_ => progressRing.IsActive = false);`
- Specific to `ListView`/`ItemsControl`: You could check that the list actually has item views with the `ContainerFromIndex()` method, eg `listView.ContainerFromIndex(expectedIndex) != null`. Be careful as the list only creates containers for items that are actually in view.
- Specific to `Image`: Images sourced from remote urls are loaded asynchronously. You can subscribe to the [`ImageOpened` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imageopened) to get a callback when the image is ready.

You'll probably need to experiment to find what works best in your scenario; this is not an exact science. If possible, it's a good idea to test across multiple devices with a range of performances.

Comment: I'd like to do a follow up on this.  CoreDispatcher solution did not seem to work.  It would return false and there would still be a significant lag before the images are displayed.  ContainerFromIndex() does the same thing regardless of what index I set.  I will add that a progress indicator is also problematic because it actually freezes during the rendering process, so it looks like the app freezes up.  I can't believe I'm the only one seeing this on wasm platform builds.

Comment: Indeed Images are handled somewhat differently than other controls, I've added some specific information. 
For the progress indicator freezing, that's a limitation of animations on WASM currently, which are run on the UI thread. There might be alternative approaches, but I would suggest asking a new question specifically about that.